# can you use the del statement inside a for loop in python

Tags: python

I want to remove the last two elements using the declaration of `del`

```
Beatles = ['John Lennon', 'Paul McCartney', 'George Harrison', 'Stu Sutcliffe', 'Pete Best']
for i in range(len(Beatles)):
    if Beatles[i] == 'Stu Sutcliffe' or Beatles[i] == 'Pete Best':
        print(i,Beatles[i]) #I print the index, to see if it is correct.
        del Beatles[i]
print("List:", Beatles)
```

When I run it I get the following message:

```
if Beatles[i] == 'Stu Sutcliffe' or Beatles[i] == 'Pete Best':
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It tells me that it is out of range, but it is strange since I visually validated that the index to be deleted is correct, I don't know if the instruction does not work inside the loop, since outside it works by passing the index [3] and [4].

```
del Beatles[3]
del Beatles[4]
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to modify a list while iterating over it. This fails on the last iteration because `i` will be `4` but since you deleted one item already your list will only have 4 items so the last index will be `3`

Comment: I had not realized the situation, which
"fails on the last iteration because it already removed an element out of 4, so the last index will be 3"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use a while loop

```
Beatles = ['John Lennon', 'Paul McCartney', 'George Harrison', 'Stu Sutcliffe', 'Pete Best']
i = 0
while i < len(Beatles):
    if Beatles[i] == 'Stu Sutcliffe' or Beatles[i] == 'Pete Best':
        print(i,Beatles[i]) #I print the index, to see if it is correct.
        del Beatles[i]
    else:
        i = i + 1
print("List:", Beatles)
```

result

```
3 Stu Sutcliffe
3 Pete Best
List: ['John Lennon', 'Paul McCartney', 'George Harrison']
```